# how to import a custom website into Wordpress

Tags: import, static-website

I've decided to try out Wordpress for the first time, so apologies if this is a nooby question. I want to try and make a basic template website, based on something that was already provided. I currently have a local static website (html, css & js files) and would like to import this into Wordpress so I can manage my content through them. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation on how to create a theme on the codex: [Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

You can also get started quickly with basic starter themes; [*underscores*](http://underscores.me/).

There are also tools that you can use to package and distribute your theme; [`wp dist-archive`](https://runcommand.io/wp/dist-archive/)

Comment: Thank you. Currently, my static website is heavily based upon https://html5up.net/arcana with only minor changes (colors and images mostly). I chose that one because of its looks and responsiveness. Would you recommend I try to import it to Wordpress or Just pick a Wordpress template and modify that?

Comment: If you want to learn, just hack in the pieces into a boiler plate theme. You don't need all the bells and whistles. If you want to go for speed then get a theme that's closer to arcana. There are enough tool and examples on how to build a theme --- which is just segmented parts put together at runtime. something like https://generatewp.com/ can help you do the internals a little faster.

Comment: I think I'm gonna go for the latter tbh. This Wordpress thingy is almost certainly more of a one-time thing, rather than anything I aim to specialize myself in. I'm more of a .NET kind of dev, but non-IT people can't dive into code. Anyway, thanks for the advice!

Comment: https://wphierarchy.com/ shows a good diagram of the possible pages you could modify.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom theme from your static website. Many tutorials about that for example here http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-wordpress-theme-html-1/

Then You just copy your's content into pages,posts or custom post type in CMS. If you got a lot of content, you can create xml or csv file, and import It to wordpress.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks. What about JS though? I don't see any of that mentioned on first sight. My current site does have JS, though I should mention it's a template on its own I downloaded. I'm unsure what would be easiest; import the site in regards to your link, or just remake it. The website has basically a fancy header, a nav-bar and a few empty pages.

Comment: what do you mean by JS ? You just add JS library to your template in functions.php   http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/ .